# How to remove 'required' setting from form field using jQuery unobtrusive validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I am having some trouble removing 'required' field validation from a field on a form that is using jQuery validation and jQuery unobtrusive.

I have the following razor view -

```
    <div class="form-group @Html.Raw(Html.HasError(x => x.TargetNumber) ? "has-error" : null)">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p><strong>How much will you raise</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TargetNumber, new { id = "TargetNumber", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Target", type = "number", Value="Target" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TargetNumber, null, new { @class = "error" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and view model

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid value.")]
    [Range(100, Double.PositiveInfinity, ErrorMessage = "The minimum amount for this event is £100")]
    public double TargetNumber { get; set; }
```

I have tried the following to make the field non required -

- Removed the [Required] attribute but still the field gets the form
  markup is renderered with various data attributes and is required
- Added data_val="false" (and required="false") to 'TextBoxFor' in the view

Yet, still the field is flagged as required on submit.

Can anyone please suggest a way that I can make this field non required.

Thanks,

Comment: How about changing the type to a `nullable` double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For structs, the `RequiredAttribute` only changes the error message, the properties are always required.
If you don't want them to be required, you need to make them nullable:

```
[Range(100, Double.PositiveInfinity, ErrorMessage = "The minimum amount for this event is £100")]
public double? TargetNumber { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a rule for your property using jQuery like so:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        TargetNumber: {
            required: function (element) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

`TargetNumber` should be the `name` attribute and not the `id` attribute. I think for MVC it automatically assigns the `name` attribute based on the model name, but check in your developer tools to see what value is being assigned to the `name` attribute.